# Visual Studio 22 missing the "this." reference when updated

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

Every time I update something in windows forms, the references in "Designer.cs" file are deleted.

Exemple:

Before:

```
this.gbUserInfo.Controls.Add(this.btnSignIn);
this.gbUserInfo.Controls.Add(this.txtPartner);
this.gbUserInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblPartner);
this.gbUserInfo.Controls.Add(this.txtPassword);
```

after i update anything in the forms:

```
gbUserInfo.Controls.Add(btnSignIn);
gbUserInfo.Controls.Add(txtPartner);
gbUserInfo.Controls.Add(lblPartner);
gbUserInfo.Controls.Add(txtPassword);
```

It applies for all the file, so I have to rewrite manually.

Anyone knows what I can do about it?

I tried to uninstall and install again, import settings from another machine that is ok, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Usually these things work with or without `this.`

Comment: This is expected. Read this article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/winforms-codegen-update/